# JQuery toggle VAT switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, toggle, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to implement a VAT switcher as you can see on [http://aria.co.uk](http://www.aria.co.uk) top right corner although I  want to do it on the client side only.

Below is something I came up with, although I need to:

- switch VAT back and forth (my example goes just one way)
- save and read the toggled state from a cookie for persistency
- have it unobtrusive / display the switch link only if JS is available

  `<html>`

  `<head>`

  `<title>VAT Switch</title>`

  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>`

  `<script type="text/javascript">`

  `function VATswitch(){`

  `var price = $(".price strong span").text();`

  `price = price * 10  / 12;`

  `$(".price strong span").text(price);`

  `var excl_incl = $(".price em").text();`

  `excl_incl = "(excl. VAT)";`

  `$(".price em").text(excl_incl);`

  `}`
  `</script>`

  `</head>`

  `<body>`

  `<a href="#" onclick="VATswitch();" id="vat_switch">Switch VAT</a>`

  `<p class="price">`

  `<strong>£<span>120</span></strong>`

  `<em>(incl. VAT)</em>`

  `</p>`

  `</body>`

  `</html>`

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to render both prices to your page and then control the visibility with jquery/css, something like:

```
<div class="price">
    <span class="incVAT">£11.50 (incl VAT)</span>
    <span class="exVAT">£10.00 (ex VAT)</span>
</div>
```

Then your toggler can do:

```
$('.price .incVAT').show();
$('.price .exVAT').hide();
```

and vice versa

Edit: I wouldn't do the calculations client side. Presumably you're making a shop of some kind, well not all your products will have VAT, and some may have different rates.

Edit re comment:

There is a [jquery cookie library](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) that will help you do the cookies, so all you need to do to persist it is read the value on load:

```
$(function(){

    ShowPrices();

    $('a#vattoggle').click(function(){
        if($.cookie('VATMODE') == "INC"){
            $.cookie('VATMODE', 'EX');
        } else {
             $.cookie('VATMODE', 'INC')
        }
        ShowPrices();
        return false
    });
});


function ShowPrices(){
    if($.cookie('VATMODE') == "INC"){
        $('.price .incVAT').show();
        $('.price .exVAT').hide();
    } else {
        $('.price .incVAT').hide();
        $('.price .exVAT').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: All of them do have VAT the same VAT. What is the best way to make it actually toggle and how do I make it persistent.